# Binary file gives EOF exception and does not read entire file using java

Tags: java

I have written the following code to convert a ASCII text file to a binary file:

```
public static void main(String args[]){
 DataOutputStream dos = null; Scanner input = null;          
try{
         dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("zipbinary.txt"));
         input = new Scanner(new BufferedReader(new FileReader("zipcode.txt")));
     int zip = 0; double lat = 0; double longt = 0;
    while (input.hasNext()){                     
                      zip = input.nextInt(); 
                  lat = input.nextDouble();
                  longt = input.nextDouble();
                  dos.writeChar(zip);
              dos.writeChar('\t');
              dos.writeDouble(lat);
              dos.writeChar('\t');
              dos.writeDouble(longt);
              dos.writeChar('\n');
     }
```

I read the binary file from another program as follows:

```
 m_dis = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(m_ZipPath)));
       while (m_dis.available() != 0){
             zipcode = m_dis.readChar();
             String zip = String.valueOf(zipcode);
             m_dis.readChar(); // throws out the tab
             m_dblLat2 = m_dis.readDouble();
             m_dis.readChar(); // throws out the tab
             m_dblLong2 = m_dis.readDouble();
            }
```

A sample entry in the text file is: 00501 40.815400 -73.045600 - All entries are in the same format.
The entries I get in the binary file are as follows:
o            @Dh -o"F   ARBeC,Y
J3/4j3{      @22^e

The no of lines in the binary file are 1/3 more than the text file, but the output is 1/3 less than the text file. And EOFException is thrown. Not that it does not work, but the output is severely constrained. As to why I am even doing this, to speed up java.io, which does not seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong where? Any suggestions appreciated.

Jimmy

Comment: You might want to close the file to make sure everything's flushed.

Comment: I have closed the stream as follows:

Comment: I have closed the stream as follows: catch(IOException e){e.printStackTrace ();}
     finally{if (m_dis != null){try {m_dis.close();}
           catch (IOException e) {System.out.println("Exception: " + e); e.printStackTrace ();}
        m_dis = null;
      }

Comment: Either use a Serializable row class or a proper TSV parser. This hybrid approach is a bad idea.

Comment: I am not that familiar with Java to even know about Serializable row class or a proper TSV parser. Details would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

`dos.writeChar(zip)` doesn't do what you think it does. You read it in as an int, something like 10023, then write it out as a *char*, i.e. character code 10023. Then you read it in as a String.

Comment: readChar() is supposed to read integers written by writeChar() as per Java SE6 DataOutputStream and DataInputStream class methods. So what should I be using?

Comment: I don't think available() does what you mean, either.

Comment: available() is a method inherited from FileInputStream() which "Returns an estimate of the number of remaining bytes that can be read (or skipped over) from this input stream without blocking by the next invocation of a method for this input stream." Emphasis on the words "remaining bytes", not total bytes in the file. If that is the problem, I don't know? "Remaining" from where, the last read? I am not reading the new line at the present, but I tried doing that by adding m_dis.readChar(); after the last line and that did not help either.

Comment: By the way, i/o while (m_dis.available() != 0) I used for(long i=0; i<(binary file length); i++) and that did not help either!

Comment: I revised my code as per: http://www.coderanch.com/how-to/java/AvailableDoesntDoWhatYouThinkItDoes and instead of for loop above, revised to: int bytesRead = 0; byte[] buffer = new byte[(int)length];//takes only int
          while ((bytesRead = m_dis.read(buffer)) != -1) { and everything is still the same!